# I lost my passport, can I leave the USA?

Tags: usa, passports, colombia

I had lost my passport a couple weeks ago and what I want to know is that if I can leave the USA without a passport. More specifically I am going to Colombia.

Comment: What country was your passport from?

Comment: If you lose your passport, the very first thing you should do is contact your embassy. **YOU SHOULD NEVER WAIT TWO WEEKS** before doing this, because it may take a little time for the embassy to issue you emergency travel documents, and you might also need to file a police report with the local police. Contact the embassy the very minute you are sure the passport is lost.

Comment: Similarly, if it is a USA passport lost in the USA, see [Lost or Stolen U.S. Passports](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/lost-stolen.html): "If your passport has been lost or stolen, it should be reported immediately to help protect yourself against identity theft and to prevent someone else from using the passport." and gives procedures for getting a replacement.

Comment: without knowing if you are planning to visit Colombia or return to your home of Colombia, this really can't be answered.

Comment: Anyone can leave the US; the US has no exit checks. The real questions are 1) can you enter the destination country, and 2) will the airline let you board.

Answer (score 2):

If you are US citizen, no. The airplane won't let you on board. If you are a Colombian citizen, and the USA doesn't want you to stay in the USA, they will likely find a way to get you to Colombia without a passport. If you are citizen of an unrelated country (say British), the USA won't mind, but the airline won't let you on board.

You should immediately report your passport as lost. Possibly to the police (just in case someone finds your passport and later intentionally drops it at a crime scene), and your embassy if you are not US citizen, who will tell you who else should know.

Comment: Even if the OP is a Colombian citizen, it is unlikely that the airline would let him board a flight to Columbia without an emergency travel document, since they are not likely to just accepts his word for having the right to enter the destination country.